# How to setup custom donation amount with Stripe with rails

Tags: stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 & I am curious on how I could go about setting up a custom amount that my donators can set for my website.

I am just asking how this could be done. I am pretty new to rails. My version is Rails 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So regardless of the web framework you're using the request will always be the same on the backend.  You're always going to call the Create a Charge [1] API Request.  The thing that will change is the `amount`-argument.

What you need to consider is how you're collecting the variable amounts on your front-end.  Checkout [2] doesn't give you the freedom to customize your form that much, so this might be better suited to Stripe.js [3].

If you do decide to go the route of Checkout, you'll need to build out something like this:

https://jsbin.com/lizafafahi/1/edit?html,output

Note that the actual amount is outside of the Checkout modal.  That is the only place you can change.

If you're feeling daring though and decide to go with Stripe.js, you'll be able to fully customize the payment experience from start to finish.  I'd definitely take a look over some tutorials on how to build out HTML Forms and then look at how to Build out HTML Forms that tie into Rails after.

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
- http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/how-to-make-a-form.phtml

Personally, I would avoid the use of form-helpers in this case, simply because you need to build a tie-in to Stripe.js, but that could just be a personal preference.

I hope that all makes sense!

---

1. https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge
2. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout
3. https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js